# I'm having trouble saving my Python (selenium) output to a txt file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble saving my output to a file. I'm using the following script (note this is an Australian website):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

    chrome_path =r"C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get("https://pointsbet.com.au/basketball/NBA")

    time.sleep(2)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/sport-competition-component/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/event-list/div[1]/event/div/header/div[1]/h2/a""").click()
    time.sleep(2)


    posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("market")
    for post in posts:
        print(post.text)


    with open('output12.txt',mode ='w') as f:
        f.write(str(post))
```

the output in the txt file come out as:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="af079b982b14f33d736b6745ad6e9648", element="0.8397874328987758-6")>
```

it should come out as something like this (depending on the websites data at that point in time):

HEAD TO HEAD
Memphis Grizzlies
1.55
Miami Heat
2.53
LINE
Memphis Grizzlies -4.0
1.92
Miami Heat +4.0
1.92
TOTAL POINTS
Over 195.5
1.87
Under 195.5
1.96
NAME A BET FEATURE
Mike Conley and Marc Gasol To Combine For 41+ Points
2.50

The above is how the text prints when the script is run.

ANy help would be great

thanks- new to stack overflow- this is fantastic

Comment: Looking at your example code the indentation is incorrect. In Python indentation is how code blocks are formed.  What you are actually seeing is the string representation of a post object, because your write is at the same indentation level as your for loop it is printing the last post entry. Try moving the `with open` block above your for loop, and use `f.write(post.text)` within the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your `for` loop as follows and tell if it works for you : note that the `with open(...) ...` must be inside the `for` loop, not outside ! You also need to open the file in `append` mode.

```
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
    with open('output12.txt',mode ='a') as f:
        f.write(post.text)
```

The other solution, more efficient one, as pointed out by @Tommy could be:

```
with open('output12.txt',mode ='w') as f:    
        for post in posts:
            print(post.text)
            f.write(post.text)
```

Comment: This won't give the answer the op is asking for either. The open needs to be positioned before the for-loop.

Comment: You're wellcom @TommyMason . @Tim, the code will work but it is not efficient, as it will be opening the file at each single step of the `for` loop. Let move it to its best place.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output you are after (comments inline)

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("market")

# Open your output file
with open('output12.txt', mode='w') as f:
    # Iterate through the posts list
    for post in posts:
        # Print the output to both the screen and the file
        print(post.text)
        f.write(post.text)
```